# $f:[0,1)\to [0,1)$ be continuous and onto, we need to show it has a fixed point.

Tags: real-analysis

$f:[0,1)\to [0,1)$ be continuous and onto, we need to show it has a fixed point.

I considered $g(x)=f(x)-x$ which is also continuous and onto, so There exists(by Intermediate Value Theorem) $y\in [0,1)$ such that $g(y)=0\Rightarrow f(y)=y$ is it okay?

Comment: The direction is correct, but you need to add more, by dividing this into cases: like if f(0)=0, then you're done. otherwise, f(0)>0, and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}f(x)<1$, such that f(1)-1<0 such that according to the middle value theorem, you can find a value y, such that $0=g(y)=f(y)-y$

Comment: If your proof that $\operatorname{g}$ is both onto and continuous is valid then, of course, this proves the fixed point. How did you show this?

Comment: @NoySoffer Are you assuming that $\lim_{x\to 1} f(x)$ exists?

Answer (score 10):

$g$ might not necessarily be onto.  You are right to say we want to find a zero of $g$.  If $f(0)$ is not $0$, we must have $g(0)>0$.  Then, since $f$ is onto, there must be some $c>0$, with $f(c)=0$ so that $g(c)<0$.  Now use the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: You write $g$ might not be onto. That's correct, and it is not even clear which set (codomain) it was supposed to be onto. Certainly its range can go outside $[0,1)$, by your argument.